# How to shrink btrfs image file used by LXD storage?

Tags: disk-image, btrfs, lxd

I have btrfs image file set as backend for LXD (2.18) but I would like to shrink it's size. What I did:

- mounted image to loop device `losetup /dev/loop1 /home/btrfs.img`
- mounted device to /mnt dir `mount /dev/loop1 /mnt/brtfs`
- resized btrfs partition with `btrfs filesystem resize -100G /mnt/btrfs`

And after that `df` correctly shows partition size of `/mnt/btrfs`:

```
root@host:/mnt/btrfs# df -k .
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop1     1614807040 1563273068  48426164  97% /mnt/btrfs
```

but file is still with the same size

```
root@host:/home# ls -al
total 1848321632
drwx------ 2 root root          4096 Nov 11 10:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root          4096 Nov 11 10:19 ..
-rw------- 1 root root 1932735283200 Nov 11 06:29 btrfs.img
```

Later I've tried `btrfs filesystem resize -100GB /home/btrfs.img` and it didn't work according to [documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-filesystem):

> Warning: If path is a file containing a BTRFS image then resize does not work as expected and does not resize the image. This would resize the underlying filesystem instead.

My question is: how can I shrink whole file without loosing data?

Answer (score 1):

truncate -s100G /home/btrfs.img

Comment: And if I run across a file where the embedded btrfs filesystem isn't occupying all the file space, how do I "shrink-wrap" the file to match the filesystem?  I.e., where do I find the exact parameter to use with `truncate`?

Answer (score 0):

In [Automatically resize (shrink) BTRFS image file #5801](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/5801), member *stgraber* notes "There are tricks you can do to do it anyway, effectively manually creating a second loop file, adding it to btrfs as a mirror device, then removing the original, but this is slow and very much a manual process that we have no intention to automate in LXD." However, he doesn't give additional details.

The procedure below worked well for me on Ubuntu 20.04. I freed up 3GB on a VPS and it only required the one loop file.

1. Make sure you have *some* free disk space available--maybe 200MB
2. Stop LXD, locate your storage pool, and note it's current size:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop snap.lxd.daemon
   POOL=$(lxc storage list |grep ^..default |grep -Eo '/var/snap/lxd[^ ]+') && echo "POOL: $POOL"
   echo BEFORE
   sudo ls -al $POOL
   ```
3. Set your desired size in bytes:

   ```
   NEWSIZE=12000000000  # 12GB
   ```
4. Shrink the pool:

   ```
   LOOPDEV=$(sudo losetup --find --show $POOL |grep -Po /dev/loop[0-9]+); echo "LOOPDEV: $LOOPDEV"
   sudo mount $LOOPDEV /mnt
   sudo df --block-size=1 /mnt
   sudo btrfs filesystem resize $NEWSIZE /mnt
   sudo df --block-size=1 /mnt
   sudo umount /mnt
   sudo truncate --size=$NEWSIZE $POOL
   ```
5. Verify the new size and resume LXD:

   ```
   echo AFTER
   sudo ls -al $POOL
   sudo systemctl start snap.lxd.daemon
   ```

If you receive errors to any of these steps, particularly the `LOOPDEV=...`, reboot and try again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shrink step by step from gui. Sometimes disk shows 95 GB full but you can shrink to 200G at best!

`lsblk` shows mounted loop device

```
loop0    7:0    0   535G  0 loop /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/gedizsStoragePool
vda    254:0    0   550G  0 disk 
├─vda1 254:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─vda2 254:2    0 549.5G  0 part /
```

resize filesystem from gui (suppose that to 200G worked):

```
sudo gparted /dev/loop0
```

then truncate (suppose desired size is 200 GB) :

```
sudo truncate --size=200G /var/lib/lxd/disks/<yourdiskimage.img>
```

And to make sure if you need :

```
 sudo btrfs filesystem resize 200G /var/lib/lxd/storage-pools/gedizsStoragePool
```